# (OpenBuildings/Spiderling) Curl "session" throws exception Failed to connect to localhost port 4581: Connection refused

Tags: php, ssl

I am trying to make a crawl project using [OpenBuildings/Spiderling](https://github.com/OpenBuildings/spiderling).

I want to create a `Phantomjs` driver like this:

```
$phantomjs_driver = new Driver_Phantomjs();
$page = new Page($phantomjs_driver);
$page->visit($url);
```

But it throw an error:

> Curl "session" throws exception Failed to connect to localhost
>   port 4581: Connection refused

I have install phantomjs, and I try to run

```
phantomjs phantom.js 4581 phantomjs-connection.js --ssl-protocol=any --ignore-ssl-errors=true
```

on my cmd, but it does not work.

Comment: Did you check whether port 4581 is occupied by an another process?

Comment: @JeroenHeier tks for your help, i don't know why but now it run okay. maybe what you said is right. thank u!